AWX smart inventory not working with Ansible Facts
Is there any requirements to filter using Ansible facts from AWX?
For example:
curl -skL -u "admin:Ansible123!" "https://awx.example.com/api/v2/hosts/?host_filter=ansible_facts__ansible_system=Linux"

Will show 0 hosts:
{"count":0,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[]}

While I have 2 CentOS nodes managed by my current AWX.
I also noticed that facts are empty here "Inventory"-->"Hosts"-->"Facts"

I'm using AWX on K3S.
My initial question was: Is there a possible reason why I can't have my node facts or filter based on facts?
I realized that I should run a playbook to gather facts from the managed nodes before using facts. For example, based on my understanding, I can create a GatherFact job in a workflow followed by another job that syncs the inventory based on the facts to be able to use them in a final job. Is this a clean way to do it? Are there any other alternative ways that are cleaner/better?
